# Optimization for implementation of Game of Life

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, conways-game-of-life

To represent all the cells I'm using a variable `std::vector<bool> cells` to represent the cells where `true` represents a live cell. To update the canvas, I have a variable `std::vector<int> neighborCounts`, where `neighborCounts[i]` represents how many live neighbors `cell[i]` has. In the update loop, I loop through all the cells, and if its a live cell, I add 1 to the `neighborCounts` of all the adjacent cells. Then after determining all of the neighbors, I once again loop through all the cells and perform the updates based on the number of neighbors it has.

```
std::vector<int> neighborCounts(NUM_ROWS * ROW_SIZE, 0);
for (int x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < NUM_ROWS; y++)
    {
        if (cells[convertCoord(x, y)])
        {
            for (int m = x - 1; m <= x + 1; m++)
            {
                for (int n = y - 1; n <= y + 1; n++)
                {
                    if (!(m == x && n == y) && m >= 0 && m < ROW_SIZE && n >= 0 && n < NUM_ROWS)
                    {
                        neighborCounts[convertCoord(m, n)] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
for (int x = 0; x < ROW_SIZE; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < NUM_ROWS; y++)
    {
        int coord = convertCoord(x, y);
        int numNeighbors = neighborCounts[coord];
        if (cells[coord])
        {
            if (numNeighbors < 2)
            {
                cells[coord] = false;
            }
            else if (numNeighbors > 3)
            {
                cells[coord] = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (numNeighbors == 3)
            {
                cells[coord] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the render function, I loop through all the cells and if its alive I draw it to the screen.

This seems to be the most straightforward way to do this, but there's definitely room for further optimization. How do powder toys and other apps manage a huge array of particles and yet still manage to run amazingly smooth? What is the most efficient way to manage all the cells in Conway's Game of Life?

Comment: I'd at least start with tiles.  A 4x4 tile is 16 bits of possible state.  A map from 4x4 tile to the state of the inner 2x2 subtile can be generated.  Bit operations can be done to generate overlapping tile results (bit shuffling can take two 4x4 tiles, and generate the state index of the 4x4 half-overlap, or 4 4x4 tiles and generate the 4x4 tile of the corner overlap).  Almost completely branchless.  Then I'd be tempted to gpu it.

Comment: read this: http://downloads.gamedev.net/pdf/gpbb/gpbb17.pdf